# Generating TFRecord for COCO dataset

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I am building an object detector using TensorFlow library. I am trying to convert COCO 2017 dataset to TFRecord, but I am getting this error massage.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/create_coco_tf_record.py", line 283, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/create_coco_tf_record.py", line 267, in main
    num_shards=100)
  File "/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/create_coco_tf_record.py", line 211, in _create_tf_record_from_coco_annotations
    groundtruth_data = json.load(fid,('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

I typed in jupyter notebook this code:

```
!python /Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/create_coco_tf_record.py --logtostderr \
      --train_image_dir=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --val_image_dir=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --test_image_dir=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --train_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --val_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --testdev_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \
      --output_dir=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images/train.record
```

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

did you download data set and labels form the coco official website 
if you do so, follow the comment in the py file

```
"""
Example usage:
    python create_coco_tf_record.py --logtostderr \
      --train_image_dir="${TRAIN_IMAGE_DIR}" \
      --val_image_dir="${VAL_IMAGE_DIR}" \
      --test_image_dir="${TEST_IMAGE_DIR}" \
      --train_annotations_file="${TRAIN_ANNOTATIONS_FILE}" \
      --val_annotations_file="${VAL_ANNOTATIONS_FILE}" \
      --testdev_annotations_file="${TESTDEV_ANNOTATIONS_FILE}" \
      --output_dir="${OUTPUT_DIR}"
"""
```

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the dataset from coco official website. I followed the comment, but I am still getting same error. I am using create_coco_tf_record.py code.

Comment: which os do you use?

Comment: I am using Mac OS

Comment: Yes, I add it on the question. Thanks

Comment: train_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \ --val_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images \ --testdev_annotations_file=/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/images

Comment: this should be all somepath/sth.json

Comment: Thanks tom, it works. However, I got another error: File "/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Models/models-master/research/object_detection/Obj_Det/create_coco_tf_record.py", line 227, in _create_tf_record_from_coco_annotations
    image_id = image['id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers. Any suggestions

Comment: Any idea how I can do the reverse? i.e. go from tf-record to json? I have all my test data is tf-record, but I need it in json for validation (I'm trying RetinaNet).